# SetLayeredWindowAttributes with disabled Aero

Tags: c++, mfc, aero

I have a program that puts a transparent window on top of the desktop where a user can do some free hand drawing with the mouse. The program works fine as long as Aero is enabled but when Aero is disabled (on Windows 7) it fails - I cannot draw and the mouse doesn't change to the mouse shape I set for the window.

The code looks like this (MFC):

```
//=============================================================================
//    PreCreateWindow
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    Public function to create the window based on global properties
//=============================================================================
BOOL CDrawWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
   HBRUSH   hBgBrush  = ::CreateSolidBrush(m_crBackgroundColor);
   HCURSOR  hcursor = NULL;
   if (m_uiCursor)
      hcursor = AfxGetApp()->LoadCursor(m_uiCursor);
   else if (m_Cursor)
       hcursor = AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(m_Cursor); // By default IDC_CROSS

    try
    {
        cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, hcursor, hBgBrush);
    }
    catch(.../*CResourceException ex*/)
    {
        /*ex.ReportError();*/
      MessageBox(_T("AfxRegisterWndClass failed"));
    }

   return CWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}


//=============================================================================
//    CreateWnd
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    Public function to create the window based on global properties
//=============================================================================
bool CDrawWnd::CreateWnd()
{
   CreateEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, _T("WsmLayeredWindowClass"), _T("Layered Draw Window"), WS_POPUP, m_StartWndRect, NULL, NULL, NULL);

   if (m_hWnd)
   {
      // Make this window transparent
      if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_crBackgroundColor, (255 * m_Transparency) / 100, LWA_COLORKEY))
      {
         TRACE(_T("\nSetLayeredWindowAttributes failed: 0x%lX"), GetLastError());
      }

      ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

      GetWindowRect(&m_rDrawingSurface);

      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

CDrawWnd is derived from CWnd. CDrawWnd::CreateWnd() is called to create the window. In the case it doesn't work

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_crBackgroundColor, (255 * m_Transparency) / 100, LWA_COLORKEY)
```

fails even though GetLastError() returns 0.

Comment: [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540.aspx): *"If the function fails, the return value is zero."*

Comment: Also note the rules for hit testing outlined at [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#layered). Since you are using color keying (vs. alpha transparency) I would assume that the observed behavior is to be expected: All areas of the window with a color of `m_crBackgroundColor` are interpreted as fully transparent, and mouse messages go to the window underneath.

Comment: As for the return value of SetLayeredWindowAttributes you are right, I miss a '!' that I had in the original source but somehow missed in one of the numerous tests.

Comment: As for the second comment about hit testing, can you explain why it works with Aero enabled and not with Aero disabled?

Comment: The introduction of the Desktop Window Manager with Windows Vista was a fairly radical change, and I often find myself wondering about the accuracy of the documentation. Frankly, I don't know why it appears to work with Aero enabled. What you can try, if even for testing, is to set low alpha transparency (passing `1` and `LWA_ALPHA`). This should produce the desired result, but your overlay window will no longer be invisible. A solution that will always work is to install a global `WH_MOUSE` hook (see [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)).

Comment: You are taking a dependency on a bug in Aero.  It fails to make the window transparent to mouse clicks for *some* background colors.  Covered pretty well in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27403681/17034).  No, there is no workaround.